# Can't find a solution to a python attribute error. Stuck on web scraping tutorial

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

This is the page i am scraping from:
https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=34.0997&lon=-118.3354#.XvnsCihKjIU

and I am looking to extract the classes period-name, short-desc and temp but for some reason when following the tutorial I get an attribute error come up on PyCharm!

```
<!-- 7-Day Forecast -->
<div id="seven-day-forecast" class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <b>Extended Forecast for</b>
    <h2 class="panel-title">
                Hollywood CA    </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" id="seven-day-forecast-body">
            <div id="seven-day-forecast-container"><ul id="seven-day-forecast-list" class="list-unstyled"><li class="forecast-tombstone">
<div class="tombstone-container">
<p class="period-name">Today<br><br></p>
<p><img src="DualImage.php?i=ra&j=sct&ip=20" alt="Today: Areas of drizzle before 11am.  Cloudy through mid morning, then gradual clearing, with a high near 71. South southeast wind 5 to 10 mph becoming southwest in the afternoon. " title="Today: Areas of drizzle before 11am.  Cloudy through mid morning, then gradual clearing, with a high near 71. South southeast wind 5 to 10 mph becoming southwest in the afternoon. " class="forecast-icon"></p><p class="short-desc">Areas Drizzle<br>then Mostly<br>Sunny</p><p class="temp temp-high">High: 71 &deg;F</p></div></li><li class="forecast-tombstone">
<div class="tombstone-container">
<p class="period-name">Tonight<br><br></p>
<p><img src="newimages/medium/nfg.png" alt="Tonight: Patchy fog after 11pm.  Otherwise, increasing clouds, with a low around 57. South southwest wind 5 to 10 mph becoming light  in the evening. " title="Tonight: Patchy fog after 11pm.  Otherwise, increasing clouds, with a low around 57. South southwest wind 5 to 10 mph becoming light  in the evening. " class="forecast-icon"></p><p class="short-desc">Patchy Fog</p><p class="temp temp-low">Low: 57 &deg;F</p></div></li><li class="forecast-tombstone">
<div class="tombstone-container">
<p class="period-name">Tuesday<br><br></p>
<p><img src="DualImage.php?i=fg&j=few" alt="Tuesday: Patchy fog before 11am.  Otherwise, cloudy through mid morning, then gradual clearing, with a high near 76. Calm wind becoming south southwest around 5 mph in the afternoon. " title="Tuesday: Patchy fog before 11am.  Otherwise, cloudy through mid morning, then gradual clearing, with a high near 76. Calm wind becoming south southwest around 5 mph in the afternoon. " class="forecast-icon"></p><p class="short-desc">Patchy Fog<br>then Sunny</p><p class="temp temp-high">High: 76 &deg;F</p></div></li><li class="forecast-tombstone">
<div class="tombstone-container">
<p class="period-name">Tuesday<br>Night</p>
<p><img src="newimages/medium/nfg.png" alt="Tuesday Night: Patchy fog after 11pm.  Otherwise, increasing clouds, with a low around 59. South southwest wind around 5 mph becoming calm  after midnight. " title="Tuesday Night: Patchy fog after 11pm.  Otherwise, increasing clouds, with a low around 59. South southwest wind around 5 mph becoming calm  after midnight. " class="forecast-icon"></p><p class="short-desc">Patchy Fog</p><p class="temp temp-low">Low: 59 &deg;F</p></div></li><li class="forecast-tombstone">
<div class="tombstone-container">
<p class="period-name">Wednesday<br><br></p>
<p><img src="DualImage.php?i=fg&j=few" alt="Wednesday: Patchy fog before 11am.  Otherwise, mostly sunny, with a high near 76. Light southeast wind becoming south southwest 5 to 10 mph in the afternoon. Winds could gust as high as 15 mph. " title="Wednesday: Patchy fog before 11am.  Otherwise, mostly sunny, with a high near 76. Light southeast wind becoming south southwest 5 to 10 mph in the afternoon. Winds could gust as high as 15 mph. " class="forecast-icon"></p><p class="short-desc">Patchy Fog<br>then Sunny</p><p class="temp temp-high">High: 76 &deg;F</p></div></li><li class="forecast-tombstone">
<div class="tombstone-container">
<p class="period-name">Wednesday<br>Night</p>
<p><img src="newimages/medium/nfg.png" alt="Wednesday Night: Patchy fog after 11pm.  Otherwise, mostly cloudy, with a low around 59." title="Wednesday Night: Patchy fog after 11pm.  Otherwise, mostly cloudy, with a low around 59." class="forecast-icon"></p><p class="short-desc">Patchy Fog</p><p class="temp temp-low">Low: 59 &deg;F</p></div></li><li class="forecast-tombstone">
<div class="tombstone-container">
<p class="period-name">Thursday<br><br></p>
<p><img src="DualImage.php?i=fg&j=skc" alt="Thursday: Patchy fog before 11am.  Otherwise, mostly sunny, with a high near 79." title="Thursday: Patchy fog before 11am.  Otherwise, mostly sunny, with a high near 79." class="forecast-icon"></p><p class="short-desc">Patchy Fog<br>then Sunny</p><p class="temp temp-high">High: 79 &deg;F</p></div></li><li class="forecast-tombstone">
<div class="tombstone-container">
<p class="period-name">Thursday<br>Night</p>
<p><img src="newimages/medium/nfg.png" alt="Thursday Night: Patchy fog after 11pm.  Otherwise, mostly cloudy, with a low around 59." title="Thursday Night: Patchy fog after 11pm.  Otherwise, mostly cloudy, with a low around 59." class="forecast-icon"></p><p class="short-desc">Patchy Fog</p><p class="temp temp-low">Low: 59 &deg;F</p></div></li><li class="forecast-tombstone">
<div class="tombstone-container">
<p class="period-name">Friday<br><br></p>
<p><img src="DualImage.php?i=fg&j=skc" alt="Friday: Patchy fog before 11am.  Otherwise, mostly sunny, with a high near 83." title="Friday: Patchy fog before 11am.  Otherwise, mostly sunny, with a high near 83." class="forecast-icon"></p><p class="short-desc">Patchy Fog<br>then Sunny</p><p class="temp temp-high">High: 83 &deg;F</p></div></li></ul></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
// equalize forecast heights
$(function () {
    var maxh = 0;
    $(".forecast-tombstone .short-desc").each(function () {
        var h = $(this).height();
        if (h > maxh) { maxh = h; }
    });
    $(".forecast-tombstone .short-desc").height(maxh);
});
</script>   </div>
</div>

<!-- Everything between 7-Day Forecast and Footer goes in this row -->
```

This is the code I have written so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=34.0997&lon=-118.3354#.XvnsCihKjIU')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
week = soup.find(id='seven-day-forecast-body')
items = week.find_all(class_='tombstone-container')
#print(items[0])
print(items[0]).find(class_="period-name").get_text())
```

and this is the error I am getting:

```
print(items[0]).find(class_="period-name").get_text())
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: unmatched ')'
```

If you wish to see the video I am watching a tutorial by 'clever Programmer' on YouTube
Title = 20 - web scraping with python using beautiful soup & requests

Please help

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

That means that you have an error with your parenthesis in your print statement. If you put a "(" right after print and before "(items)" in your final statement it should remove that error.